# Why PERL5LIB env variable is disappeared after `source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc`?

Tags: docker, perl, dockerfile

In my `Dockerfile` I have next command:

```
FROM perl:5.30.3-buster
...
RUN  env && source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc &&  env  &&  carton install
```

when `source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc` was executed the `PERL5LIB` is disappeared and `carton` can not find libraries indicated by `PERL5LIB` path

Output from command:

```
Step 18/22 : RUN  env && source $PERLBREW_ROOT/etc/bashrc &&  env  &&  carton install
 ---> Running in 358cb3aa042e
HOSTNAME=358cb3aa042e
PERL_VERSION=5.34.1
PERLBREW_HOME=/opt/perlbrew/home
PWD=/
HOME=/root
PERL5LIB=/opt/proj/lib:/opt/proj/local/lib/perl5:
SHLVL=1
PATH=/opt/perlbrew/bin:/opt/proj/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew
_=/usr/bin/env

HOSTNAME=358cb3aa042e
PERL_VERSION=5.34.1
PERLBREW_PATH=/opt/perlbrew/bin:/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.1/bin
PERLBREW_HOME=/opt/perlbrew/home
PERLBREW_SHELLRC_VERSION=0.94
PWD=/
MANPATH=/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.1/man:
PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.34.1
HOME=/root
PERLBREW_VERSION=0.94
SHLVL=1
PATH=/opt/perlbrew/bin:/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.1/bin:/opt/proj/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PERLBREW_ROOT=/opt/perlbrew
PERLBREW_MANPATH=/opt/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.34.1/man
_=/usr/bin/env
```

But running same command on host system does not wipe `PERL5LIB`:

```
(env | grep PERL) && source ~/perl5/perlbrew/etc/bashrc && (env | grep PERL)
PERLBREW_PATH=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/bin
PERLBREW_HOME=/home/kes/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_SHELLRC_VERSION=0.89
PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.30.3
PERLBREW=command perlbrew
PERLBREW_VERSION=0.89
PERL5LIB=xxx
PERLBREW_ROOT=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_MANPATH=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/man
PERLBREW_PATH=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/bin
PERLBREW_HOME=/home/kes/.perlbrew
PERLBREW_SHELLRC_VERSION=0.89
PERLBREW_PERL=perl-5.30.3
PERLBREW=command perlbrew
PERLBREW_VERSION=0.89
PERL5LIB=xxx
PERLBREW_ROOT=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew
PERLBREW_MANPATH=/home/kes/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.30.3/man
```

Tell me please, what is the problem when running that command from `Docker` file while building container?

Comment: Can't replicate. (v0.94) What's in `${PERLBREW_HOME:-}/init`?

Comment: @ikegami: https://pastebin.com/pLMYQjDH . Hm.. I see `unset`. For version on local host there is no `unset` https://pastebin.com/e2fWXUMW

Comment: Seems I need a way to setup and preserve ENV variables for PERLBREW for next steps while building container.

Comment: Anyway, it doesn't make much sense to use perlbrew in a script. Just use the correct `perl` by providing the full path

Comment: @ikegami: Want to have container with different versions of perl

Comment: I suppose it makes it a little bit easier to install them.

Comment: Just curious: If you are in a container, why not use the system perl it provides? and install local::lib with your app dependencies

Comment: @MiguelPrz: I just misunderstood concept. Wanna container with many perls, but better to have separate containers for each required perl. Better solution is: `ARG PERL_VERSION=5.24.1-buster; FROM perl:$PERL_VERSION` then can provide required version when building new container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @ikegami

It was `unset` by `${PERLBREW_HOME:-}/init`. This `unset` required when you switch between perls and do not want theirs libraries mixed with each other.

For example you are on perl-5.24 and have installed libraries into its `PERL5LIB`, then you switched to perl-5.28 but `PERL5LIB` still points to modules installed by different version of perl. This may cause coredumps.